# Trigger An Email

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service

I need some assistance. We would like to set up an email to be sent the day after someone has attended one of our events. Any thought on how that can be done? Thanks !

- It's based on the Campaign object. We have a specific Campaign Record Type that we will be using for these people.  Once a camapign is ended the camapaign member is set to attended. We would like to send an aiuto email to them the next day based on that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a workflow rule.
In the rule criteria, you can put the condition as date field(date field that you are using) plus 1 is today's date.

And in the workflow action, you can send an email.